# Is there any transcript or recordings of Yasser Arafat's speech to Arab foreign ministers in 1996 (Stockholm)?

Tags: israel, palestine

I am interested in a full transcript or original recording of a speech that Yasser Arafat delivered to 'Arab diplomats in Stockholm's [Grand Hotel in] January 1996'. The speech is referenced and is commentated on in these four links, which are the only ones I have been able to find that pertain to this particular speech:

https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1996-02-27-me-40531-story.html

https://iris.org.il/quotes/stockhlm.htm

https://www.geocities.ws/palestiniansarelies/YasserArafatDeclaration.html

https://www.nytimes.com/1997/08/04/world/in-the-words-of-arafat.html

It seems that the existence of this speech/its authenticity has been debated, as far as I can tell. The first link provides a direct quote to his speech, and cites the the Norwegian paper Dagen.

The second link provides context to the information from Dagen, but also discusses more detail on the debate of authenticity of the speech. Despite this contest, detailed direct quotes from his speech are sitll given.

The third also provides quotes to the speech and another newspaper, the Swedish weekly Magazine.

The last is likely the least related but a connection to other anti-peace remarks Arafat might have made.

Arafat's War: The Man and His Battle for Israeli Conquest by Efraim Karsh (Chapter 3, a Trojan Horse) seems to have provided more detail, but I couldn't find any footnotes with the online sample. I'm also still awaiting a copy of Henry Kissinger's "Does America Need a Foreign Policy?" on interlibrary loan- Page 178 seems to have detail, but no footnotes either. I can provide excerpts on Karsh's book if needed.

Anyone have any leads?

Comment: The journal Dagen isn't norwegian but it is owned by norwegian Mentor Medier.  Dagen is a swedish language conservative christian paper.

Comment: Dagen was founded by leading members of the swedish pentekostalism movement.

Comment: thank you for your reply.